# Dynamic nested lists

Tags: c++, list, dynamic, nested

Nested list is a list of lists.

```
std::list<std::list<int> > nestedList;
```

How to create multi-dimension depth dynamicly list? For examle, user enters number 3, and then  how dynamicly create 3-dimension depth nested list(list of list of lists...) ? 
I know how to declare manual, but I need to create it dynamicly.

Comment: Easier question: How do you make a program so that if the user enters "s" you create a string, and for "i" you create an int?

Comment: Just use type erasure and a variant. vOv

Comment: Concisely: I know how to do this in static: list<list<list<obj> > > (3 levels). But it is declared staticly. How to do this dynamicly(real time) ?

Comment: @user3112530 A `list<list<list<obj>>>` is it's own type. C++ is a statically typed language.

Comment: Use pointers, unions, etc...

Comment: @user3112530 What is the features of the data structure that you are looking for, exactly? list<list<int>> will be constant time iterable over the start of each "row" and over each "colum" but it will take O(width+height) to get to a given position. Before we can tell you a good data structure to use, you gotta clarify how you need to use the structure :-

Answer (score 0):

My go-to approach for simple problems like this is to allocate a vector and handle the dimensions through indexing.

For example, a 2D array of size WxH is `std::vector<int> v(W*H);`

Then access it with `int& get(int x, int y){ return v[y * W + x]; }`

You can extend this pattern to as many dimensions as you want, but it may not be suitable depending on your problem. Consider it an option.

Answer (score 0):

You could either:

- Predefine what the valid number of dimensions are so all of them can be compiled. Then use a switch and templated functions.

or

- Write a new n-d list class.

The constructor would be called along the lines of :

```
size_t dimensions(3);
ndList<int> myNDList(dimensions);
```